Adding two layers (raster and DEM) together in QGIS Graphical Modeler
I'm making an algorithm in the modeler, and I got stuck. I need to add two layers together. I have a raster layer (which used to be a vector layer, but I transformed it) and I also have a DEM layer.
How can I add these two together?
This is how the model looks so far:


Are you looking for Raster Calculator? https://docs.qgis.org/latest/en/docs/user_manual/working_with_raster/raster_analysis.html#raster-calculator

Yes, or something similar to that!

Yes, then use Raster calculator. We don't have enough information about what you want to achieve, so this is best advice I can give

If i uderstand you wanna product of rasterize  -> raster add to DEM raster? So U need add DEM as input and then use Raster calculator on both layers.
